# Ember.js - Display two table cells per row

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Ember.js and my plan is to create a table that has two table cells per row for any number of table cells, so that

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  ...
</tr>
```

would become

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  ...
</tr>
```

The closest thing I can think of to use as a reference is that it's similar to the way Facebook displays members within a Facebook group.

Currently this is what I have

```
<table id='group-member-table' class='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan='2'>Members</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      {{#each groupinfo.individuals as |member|}}
        <td>{{member.firstname}} {{member.lastname}</td>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm just a little confused on how to do this within Ember.js and having a dynamic number of members per group.

Comment: Write a Handlebars helper that - for values modulo 2 (every second value) it wraps the values with <tr> </tr> - http://www.arlocarreon.com/blog/javascript/handlebars-js-everyother-helper/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using mainly Bootstrap and CSS based off of Andrew's model

```
<div class='group-member-container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12'>
  {{#each groupinfo.individuals as |member|}}
    <div class='group-member-card col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6'>
      <div class='card'>{{member.firstname}} {{member.lastname}}</div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

And for the .scss file:

```
.group-member-container {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  .group-member-card {
    margin: 5px 0;
    .card {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve what you are attempting is add some CSS and drop the table.

```
<div id="container" style="width:250px;">
    <div style="float:left;display:inline-block;width:100px;">1</div>
    <div style="float:left;display:inline-block;width:100px;">2</div>
    <div style="float:left;display:inline-block;width:100px;">3</div>
    <div style="float:left;display:inline-block;width:100px;">4</div>
</div>
```

When the elements fill the first line, they will wrap to the next line, producing the same effect as in your table example.

The way your code is formatted, it looks like it should be:

```
<div id='group-member-container'>
  <div>
      <p>Members</p>
  </div>
  <div id="container" style="width:250px;">
      {{#each groupinfo.individuals as |member|}}
        <div style="float:left;display:inline-block;width:100px;">{{member.firstname}} {{member.lastname}</div>
      {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about going the css route after I posted the question. I think this is the path I'm going to go